# How can I predict the height of a WPF control when child controls are changed

Tags: wpf, animation

I'm writing a WPF animation on a user control. The control's height is not explicitly set; it's dependant on which child controls are visible. I'm performing an animation to reduce the height of the user control smoothly when some child controls are hidden.

However, I don't know the end height of the animation. I need to measure what the height would be, were the child controls hidden, but I can't change how the control looks before the animation is performed to do that. Ideally, I want a 'FreezeDisplay' method that I can use like this:

```
public void HideSomeControls()
{        
    double targetHeight;
    using (this.FreezeDisplay())
    {
        Control1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        Control2.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        Control3.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        targetHeight = this.ActualHeight;
    }

    this.BeginAnimation(HeightProperty, new DoubleAnimation(ActualHeight, targetHeight, ...));
}
```

But that method doesn't seem to exist. How can I accomplish what I want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit light on detail. eg. how is the animated child supposed to react to the animation? Clipping? Scaling? How are you going to revert the animation? Another animation?

Assuming the child controls are wrapped in a container and you want a clipped effect, I would animate as follows:

1. Animate the container's `Height` to its `ActualHeight` instantly.
2. Animate the container's `Height` to zero over time *t*.
3. Animate the container's `Visibility` to `Collapsed` instantly.